# compression expansion algorithm to reduce the number of digits in a phone number

Tags: algorithm, math, compression

this is more of a theoretical question . let me explain the situation first:

we have system which makes telephone call another system and sends dtmf tone ( if you are not familiar with dtmf tone, lets just assume it sends digits like 0,1,2...). based on the dtmf tones received , the receiving end composes the entire number and then performs some act.

however, with longer numbers like 423121212121 , it has 13 dtmf tones , which takes a very long time to be transmitted.

i was wondering if anyone is familiar with any kind of mathematical formula or algorithm that can compress these 13 digits into smaller size , send it over and then extract it on the other end ?

Answer (score 4):

There are, in the full-blown DTMF scheme, four "bits" of data, meaning 16 combos.  The most obvious way to approach your question, if all 16 combos are available, would be to encode your number into hex digits and transmit the hex.  This would get your 13 digits down to 10 or 11 -- not a major reduction, but maybe the best you can do.

The only other thing I can think of is to take advantage of patterns in the digits and replace, eg, "popular" prefix codes with a single digit (requiring that less common prefixes have an extra marker digit ahead to identify them).  This is a poor-man's version of Huffman encoding.  Or one could go for full-blown Huffman encoding, or a similar scheme.